# npm error trying to install the “next” version of NativeScript

Tags: npm, nativescript

I’ve been trying to install the “next” version of NativeScript using the following command.

```
npm install -g nativescript@next
```

The problem is I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! Refusing to delete /usr/local/bin/tns: ../lib/node_modules/nativescript/bin/nativescript.js symlink target is not controlled by npm /usr/local
npm ERR! File exists: /usr/local/bin/tns
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.
```

Anyone know what might be up? I tried running `npm uninstall -g nativescript` and re-reunning the install, but I ended up having the same problem.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about chmod of that file ? `/usr/local/bin/tns` ? What permissions ? Probably npm dont have permissions to delete it

Comment: Persmissions are `rwxr-xr-x`. What’s weird is that if I uninstall via `npm uninstall` the `/usr/local/bin/tns` file no longer exists, which makes me think this isn’t a permission issue. I definitely could be wrong though.

Comment: Also `tns install -g nativescript` works fine. It’s just `tns install -g nativescript@next` that fails, which means this is possibly an issue with the CLI itself.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will work for everyone, but in my case I had to clear my npm cache. After I did that this magically worked.

```
npm uninstall -g nativescript
npm cache clear
npm install -g nativescript
```